# IBM Worklight 6.0.0 - Using WebViewOverlay sample code for iOS Not Work

Tags: ios, xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

Using the Worklight v6.0.0 code sample/tutorial "Integrating server-generated pages in hybrid applications" (http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/IntegratingServerGeneratedPagesProject.zip) allows for the web content to be integrated. The code sample doesn't work in iOS 7/XCode 5. When show web view overlay page, it shows white blank page.

However, Android version works fine.

How can I get the WebViewOverlay to work on iOS 7/XCode 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Worklight Studio 6.0.0.20130926-1933, Xcode 5.0.2 and the iOS 7.0.3 simulator.  When I first imported the project, it crashed on startup.  It was something about iOS7, because it worked on the iOS6 simulator.

I deleted the iPhone environment and re-created it (including the customizations in the iPhone environment's css and js folders, and installed the WebViewOverlay plug-in in Xcode) and the crash was fixed.  At that point the app worked fine, and the WebViewOverlay opened and populated with content.  But it wouldn't close.  I had to modify the close() method in WebViewOverlayPlugin.m

```
- (void)close:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command{
    NSLog(@"WebViewOverlayPlugin :: close");

    WLCordovaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (WLCordovaAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if ([[[appDelegate window] subviews] count] > 1) {
        UIView *appView = [[[appDelegate window] subviews] objectAtIndex:1];

        for (UIView *view in [appView subviews]){

            if (view.tag==12345) {

                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }}
    }
}
```

It looks like something changed since the sample was written, and objectAtIndex:0 needed to change to: objectAtIndex:1.  Someone who actually knows objective c could probably do a better job with the condition I added (and explain why the change), but with the iPhone environment re-created, and the above implementation of close() it all seems to work on iOS 7.

Comment: Thanks, David. Tried [[[appDelegate window] subviews] objectAtIndex:1]; it gives me array out of index error. Put the objectAtIndex to 0. Didn't get the error but blank white page. Finally after dig Cordova iOS code for several hours. Used this to solve this issue: UIView *appView = self.viewController.view. It works as before iOS 5/6 and 7 now.

Comment: if you were getting the array out of index, then you missed the conditional I added, but in any case, your solution looks better.  What is confusing me is why a problem in close() was causing the web view not to load properly.  When I did it, it loaded fine, but just wouldn't close properly.

Comment: Found some issue with WLCordovaAppDelegate. It is not working like before let viewController share same wevViews added. So this is Codova way of manage webViews. You could hide/show/add animations...